# Laravel Breeze not generating migrations

Tags: php, laravel, breeze, laravel-migrations

Im following
[Laravel Breeze Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits) from Laravel's oficial page and after installing Breeze package I don't see any new migration

these are the lines i executed

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/prueba | bash
 
cd example-app
 
php artisan migrate
```

at this point I have created a new Laravel application and  `php artisan migrate` create tables correctly in my DB

```
composer require laravel/breeze --dev

php artisan breeze:install
 
npm install
npm run dev
php artisan migrate
```

at this point I have all the views for the authentication generated thanks to Breeze. but when `php artisan migrate` is executed the response I get is

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `php artisan migrate:fresh`? Maybe you've run it before

Comment: @WahyuKristianto it didn't work. there are no new migrations after installing Breeze.

Comment: Did you run with `:fresh`? `php artisan migrate:fresh`

Comment: I did. didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check migration exists in the migration folder if yes then try
check your database connection
`php artisan migrate:refresh`

Comment: No. There are no new migrations after installing breeze. thats the problem Im having .

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your folder to a directory which doesn't have any weird symbols in the name. Like: [Code] <- php doesn't always like this :)

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem too, finally i created the table manually

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();   
        $table->string('name', 250);
        $table->string('email', 250);
        $table->string('password', 250);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That simply means you run your migrations before you even installed Laravel/Breeze.

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/starter-kits) is a bit misleading because it says we should run `php artisan migrate` following the installation of Breeze because it assumes we just started a fresh Laravel project to which we added Breeze before running the migrations (and that is actually the recommended way to add Laravel/Breeze because, for instance, it overrides all the routes you may have declared in **routes/api.php**)

Otherwise, Laravel/breeze does not come with any new migration to run. You can actually check that on its [official source code](https://github.com/laravel/breeze/tree/master).